# How does Validate method of EPPlus work?

Tags: epplus

I'm using EPPlus as a calculations server. Here is my code:

```
using (var xlp = new ExcelPackage(stream))
{
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet Sheet = xlp.Workbook.Worksheets["sheet1"];
//Some code for feeding user data to excel sheet
//...

//We first invoke calculate method to let contraints of data validation get updated.
xlp.Workbook.Calculate();   

var v = Sheet.DataValidations["A1"];
if (v != null)
{
    switch (v.ValidationType.Type)
    {
        case OfficeOpenXml.DataValidation.eDataValidationType.DateTime:     
            OfficeOpenXml.DataValidation.ExcelDataValidationDateTime V1 = (OfficeOpenXml.DataValidation.ExcelDataValidationDateTime)v;
            try
            {
                //this line doesn't do any thing
                V1.Validate();
            }
            catch
            {
            }           
        break;
        case ...
    }
}
}
```

I had read somewhere that Validate() method throws exception for invalid data. It doesn't. 
My question: How to use the Validate() method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend on what the content of the cell and the settings of the validator's Operator:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/DataValidation/ExcelDataValidationOperator.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Operator for comparison between Formula and Formula2 in a validation.
/// </summary>
public enum ExcelDataValidationOperator
{
    any,
    equal,
    notEqual,
    lessThan,
    lessThanOrEqual,
    greaterThan,
    greaterThanOrEqual,
    between,
    notBetween
}
```

The `ExcelDataValidationDateTime` (eventually) derives from `ExcelDataValidationWithFormula<IExcelDataValidationFormulaDateTime>` which contains the implemenation of `Validate()`:

http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#EPPlus/DataValidation/ExcelDataValidationWithFormula.cs

```
public override void Validate()
{
    base.Validate();
    if (Operator == ExcelDataValidationOperator.between || Operator == ExcelDataValidationOperator.notBetween)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Formula2Internal))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Validation of " + Address.Address + " failed: Formula2 must be set if operator is 'between' or 'notBetween'");
        }
    }
}
```

So it will throw an exception (invalidate) when the validation operation is either `ExcelDataValidationOperator.between` or `ExcelDataValidationOperator.notBetween` and `Forumla2` is not set (not to be confused with the primary `Formula`).  In other words, it considers the validator invalid when you are using an operation which requires TWO values/formulas to compare but only one is set.

Comment: Thanks, So, doesn't it validate the cell content? content validation is to be done manually?

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadiRad  At design time, no, that function does not validate the content just the definition of the Validator itself.  When the user opens the excel file and adds content the validation will then check their input.  As far as validating the cell value in code I do not believe EPPlus has the ability as, I presume, they expect the developer to handle it.